# Removing duplicates from 1million array of dictionariies

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a HUGE list of objects.

That looks like this

```
output = [
   {
     'name': 'some name',
     'id': '1'
   }
]

clean_list = []
for i in range(len(output)):
    if output[i] not in output[i + 1:]:
        clean_list.append(output[i])
```

It's 1 million, and this is the method I'm currently using.. however it takes hours to complete this operation when my array is massive.

Is there a optimal way to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues with the code you propose.

## 1. speed of "in" test

You wrote

```
clean_list = []
```

but you really want

```
clean_list = set()
```

That way `in` completes in O(1) constant
time, rather than O(N) linear time.

The linear probe inside the `for`
gives the loop O(N^2) quadratic cost.

## 2. equality test of hashable items

Your source items look like e.g. `dict(name='some name', id=1)`.
You want to turn them into hashable tuples,
e.g. `('some name', 1)`,
so you can take advantage of `set`'s O(1) fast lookups.

```
from pprint import pp

clean = set()
for d in output:
    t = tuple(d.values())
    if t not in clean:
        clean.add(t)


pp(sorted(clean))
```

But wait! No need for checks, since a `set` will
reject attempts to add same thing twice.
So this suffices:

```
clean = set()
for d in output:
    clean.add(tuple(d.values()))
```

And now it's simple enough that a set comprehension makes sense.

```
clean = {tuple(d.values())
         for d in output}
```

---

Consider uniquifying on just `name`,
if the `id` value doesn't matter to you.

---

tl;dr: Doing ~ 10^6 operations is *way* better
than doing ~ 10^12 of them.

Answer (score 0):

for such a large dataset it makes sence to use `pandas`, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

output = [
   {'name': 'some name 1','id': '1'},
   {'name': 'some name 2','id': '2'},
   {'name': 'some name 3','id': '3'},
   {'name': 'some name 2','id': '2'}]

clean_list = pd.DataFrame(output).drop_duplicates().to_dict('records')

>>> clean_list
'''
[{'name': 'some name 1', 'id': '1'},
 {'name': 'some name 2', 'id': '2'},
 {'name': 'some name 3', 'id': '3'}]
```